# When trying to make an API call i get the error,"errorMessage" : "No recognized authentication method was provided."

Tags: api, access-token, tink

I am tyring to make an api call to trade a code for an api access token using a client id and client secret to call the TinkOAuthApi. This was supposed to return an api access token to get a successful response. However, I am receving an the error message that is in the title. My code is below.

```
curl -v https://api.tink.com/api/v1/oauth/token ^
                -d 'code=50a8d556c64b4a29af74faf3dce38bf4' ^
                -d 'client_id=${a5bf840f7e2a44a58b20dab576bd18be}' ^
                -d 'client_secret=${5c04d2ce35bb483cb916dc520d0da8c0}' ^
                -d 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```

Comment: When grant_type is authorization_code do not use `client_secret`, do not put ${} around your values it is probably used in the doc to indicate placeholder